# Finding, storing and replacing text in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, python, regex, visual-studio, replace

I have a lot of text in my editor with references in brackets. So for example.

> "This is text, welcome to my text [11]. We have several sources [23]. What can I do for you [33]"

I want to find each number in between the brackets and replace that number with an anchor tag containing it, like so `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R11">[11]</xref>` and then `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R23">[23]</xref>` What I am doing now is finding the numbers in brackets with a regex ( **\[.*?]** ) in the editor and then copy and pasting what I want to replace. This is time consuming when there are over 100 references to replace.

Is there a way to find, store it in a variable and then replace with said variable?

One possible solution I came up with is using JavaScript, however I cannot get it to work quite right, as evident by my output.

Code:

```
const document = 'This is text, welcome to my text [11]. We have several sources [23]. What can I do for you [33]'
const regex = /\[.*?\]/gm
let result = document.match(regex);

let array = result
var arrayLength = array.length;
console.log(arrayLength);
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log(document.replace(regex, '<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R' +  array[i] + '">' + array[i] + "</xref>"));
}
```

Console Output:

```
This is text, welcome to my text <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R[11]">[11]</xref>. We have several sources <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R[11]">[11]</xref>. What can I do for you <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R[11]">[11]</xref>
This is text, welcome to my text <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R[23]">[23]</xref>. We have several sources <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R[23]">[23]</xref>. What can I do for you <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R[23]">[23]</xref>
This is text, welcome to my text <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R[33]">[33]</xref>. We have several sources <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R[33]">[33]</xref>. What can I do for you <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R[33]">[33]</xref>
```

As you can see, I also need to remove the brackets from the **rid=** attribute. I also would like to get this done in the editor itself.  If it is not possible, then I figured I can use node.js and write to the file. Any other solution would also help. Should this be done in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PHP code gets it done:

```
<?php

$str = 'This is text, welcome to my text [11]. We have several sources [23]. What can I do for you [33]';

function addLink ($matches){
    $noBrackets = str_replace('[', '', $matches[0]);
    $noBrackets = str_replace(']', '', $noBrackets);
    $output = '<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R'.$noBrackets.'">'.$matches[0].'</xref>';
    return $output;
}

$newString = preg_replace_callback('#\[\d+\]#', 'addLink', $str);

echo '<p>'.$newString.'</p>';

?>
```

Comment: This is a great solution. It is achieving what I need to do. Is there away I can get this done in the editor itself? Or will I have to execute the code and then copy and paste it? Also would you have a solution when I get references like [12,42] or [11-15] ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your editor is or what it does exactly.  If it's the "Visual Studio" that I think it is, you just need the PHP extension installed to able to use PHP, but I have no idea how you have all of this implemented.  Yes, the regex can be written to include variations on what's inside that square bracket, but it needs to know what those variations look like.  That is, is it specifically those two formats that you mentioned there, or is there many many other possibile variations?

Comment: Yes, I am using VS code.This ultimately will be an HTML document. So I will need to copy and paste my output back into my original HTML? Also, yes, It is just those two formats I mentioned.

Comment: If you only need to do this alteration once, then copying and pasting it will probably be the least hassle.

Comment: If this format:  [12,42] or [11-15]  is referencing multiple links, then this will not work, because a link can only go to one place.  You would have to pick one of them.

Comment: If you want it to turn into a list of links like: [12][42] or [11][12][13][14][15] then that's a different question.  Please start a new question and let me know.  I'll work on it there.

Comment: ahhh yea, I meant hyperlinking the number 12, and then the number 42. However, you did enough. Thanks again for the help.